# MySQL: Get total each row then get total each 'group by'

Tags: mysql

Sorry about the title, I don't know what's the proper term to use.

I have this data:

[image]

I want to produce a table something like this:

[image]

I want to get the total of each 'group by' and I'm doing this code but I'm getting wrong total.

```
SELECT code, (a * b)
AS total_each_code
FROM  table1   
GROUP BY code
```

**UPDATE:** updated photos of sample data, sorry for typos.

Comment: just add sum((a * b))

Comment: Assuming the correct value for code `111` is `25` then `SELECT code, SUM(a * b)
AS total_each_code
FROM  table1   
GROUP BY code` is what you want

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your input data, for code `111` the `a*b` column is actually equal to `a+b`, but for the other codes it is equal to `a*b`

Comment: thank you @SonamTripathi!! exactly what i needed!

Comment: sorry about the data, got a typo.. will update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use sub query for this

```
select code, sum(a.total_each_code)
         from (
            SELECT code, (a * b)
                AS total_each_code
                FROM  table1   order by code
                )a 
        group by a.total_each_code
```

or just simple as

```
select code,sum(a*b) as total from table1 group by code.
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sum()` aggregation

```
SELECT code, sum(a * b)
AS total_each_code
FROM  table1   
GROUP BY code
```